# How to select all text in a UITextField using Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I'm using below code, but for some reason it's not working. Any idea?

```
textField.text = "Hello"

textField.becomeFirstResponder()

textField.selectedTextRange = self.textField.textRangeFromPosition(self.textField.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: self.textField.endOfDocument)
```

This is what I get:

[image: This is what I get:]

Comment: Any chance that "textField" and "self.textField" are different?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I solved like this:

First, implement UITextFieldDelegate in your ViewController

```
class ViewController :  UITextFieldDelegate
```

Then, set your textField delegate to "self"

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Then, add this function to your ViewController class

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRangeFromPosition(textField.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: textField.endOfDocument)
}
```

If you are already using the ViewController as delegate for other TextFields that you don't want to behave this way, you can just use a switch, like this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    switch textField {
         case yourTextField:
              textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRangeFromPosition(textField.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: textField.endOfDocument)
              break;

         case default:
              break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

None of the other answers worked for me. It turned out that I needed to place my code in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument) 
}
```

There are also some additional ways to select all text that others may find helpful:

```
// Select all without showing menu (Cut, Copy, etc)
textField.selectAll(nil)

// Select all and show menu
textField.selectAll(self)
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this works.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.selectedTextRange = self.textField.textRangeFromPosition(self.textField.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: self.textField.endOfDocument)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update for swift 4 from 2017

```swift
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument,
                                                        to: textField.endOfDocument)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer is

Hello, I make with this

```swift
  override func selectAll(_ sender: Any?) {
  textView.selectAll(sender)
  }
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in [Anton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40916396/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Answer (score -2):

If the previously solutions doesn't help try this

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
      if textField.text == "Untitled" {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              textField.selectAll(nil)
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I wasn't the person who downvoted, but I have some insight on why this may have been downvoted. UITextFieldDelegate is a protocol with an @MainActor wrapper, which means this function already runs on the main thread.