# xcode custom keyboard use button for short-cut

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard

I created a custom keyboard to fill specific text in a table. To do this I connected the button from the storyboard to the viewController.swift

```
 @IBAction func ECOAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.textDocumentProxy.insertText("ECO")
}
```

All the buttons works as desired. For easier work I want to have a button that selects all text where the buttons insert their text. Like using the short-cut <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>.
An other way is when a button is touched, the existing content is deleted before inserting the new.

I have no idea how to do it nor where to search. I appreciate any suggestion and keywords for searching a solution.

Comment: I found this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930656/how-to-select-all-text-in-a-uitextfield-using-swift/39356923

Comment: This will select all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689911/programmatically-select-all-text-in-uitextfield

Comment: Thanks - but I have no textField. I use the keyboard for a web-form. I found <code>self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()</code> but there is nothing to do it forward...